# Is it possible to define a 'private' entity and architecture in an architecture?

Tags: vhdl

I have an alu module `alu_div_pipelined` that instantiates another module (the pipeling stage). This module (entity + architecture) is declared in the same file.

```
entity declaration of div_pipelined
entity declaration of pipe stage
architecture of div_pipelined
architecture of pipe stage
```

**Is it possible to declare the private module inside an architecture region?**

There are no visibility requirements for the pipeline stage module.

Example:

```
entity alu_div_pipelined is
  generic (...);
  port (...);
end entity;

architecture rtl of alu_div_pipelined is
  ...

  entity pipe_stage is
    generic (...);
    port (...);
  end entity;

  architecture rtl of pipe_stage is
  ...
  end architecture;
begin

  gen : for i in 0 to 7 generate
    ...
  begin
    stage : entity work.pipe_stage
      generic map (...)
      port map (...);
  end generate;
end architecture;
```

Comment: Design units (primary, secondary) reside in design libraries, either reference libraries and are independently analyzed.  You could declare a concurrent procedure equivalent for your 'private' entity and architecture as an  architecture declarative item. Or you can express the pipeline as an internal block statement, making it private.  Both limit the scope and visibility of internal declarations in the pipeline 'module'. You can also simply use a separate reference library and not provide a use clause elsewhere, potentially hiding the use clause in a context declaration (-2008).

Comment: @DavidKoontz I'll look into the procedure approch. My problem is that every stage needs less input bits, so I can't use a generate statement and a 2-dimensional vector to solve this, unless I want to generate hundreds of XST warning for unused/constant/trimmed bits and registers :(. Just for further education: Is *primary* and *secondary* design unit the corrent term for 'moduls' in VHDL? You mentioned in one of the last posts that moduls are a Verilog thing.

Comment: Follow the BNF downward starting at design_file.  The word 'module is only found in the -2008 LRM, 15.9 comments, "comments do not influence the execution of a simulation module". It's usage is not supported. Where does your usage come from? I'd anticipate the equivalent to module is an entity/architecture pair.

Comment: [Comparing Verilog to VHDL Syntactically and Semantically](http://www.sandstrom.org/systemde.htm), Integrated System Design magazine 1995, follow the left column down to module.v and over to entity/architecture.  Usually when you have a pipeline narrowing it's because you do execution between stages. You can instantiate the stages with an input register. Keeps you from needing a flat name space, you deal with what goes on between stages individually. There's not much signal mixing between stages.

Comment: @DavidKoontz Yes I'm refering to an entity/architecture pair, because usually there is only one architecture for an entity. Besides the correct terms from LRM and co., module/modulisation is a common principle in programing languages. - After some testing for correctness I'll upload my solution on SE.CodeReview. Do you have an account at SE.CR?

Comment: I'm curious how you generated the interconnect signals that decrease in width. I'd probably use a 2d vector and ignore the warnings, but I'd be interested in learning a better way.

Comment: @QuantumRipple I'm using a top-level entity/architecture that provides the user interface and an entity/architecture pair called element that is recursively instantiated with decreasing generic parameters. The element has an `if (BITS >= 2) generate` and an `if (BITS = 1) generate` block. This stops the recursion :). If you write an email to my username + google, I can send you an example.

Comment: @Paebbels that makes sense. I've seen a RAM done that way with recursive instances, but I hadn't expanded the concept to general processing.